# How to group a pandas DataFrame by one column and merge the others?

Tags: python, pandas

Given (huge) pandas dataframe, where each row corresponds to a key-value pair that belongs to a product (identified by ProductKey). I would like to merge the key-value pairs into one line per ProductKey, as shown in frame_output. How can this be done efficiently?

```
import pandas as pd 

frame_input = pd.DataFrame({0:{"ProductKey":"Once","SpecificationKey":"key1","SpecificationValue":"val1"}, \
                            1:{"ProductKey":"Twice","SpecificationKey":"key21","SpecificationValue":"val21"}, \
                            2:{"ProductKey":"Twice","SpecificationKey":"key22","SpecificationValue":"val22"}}).transpose()

frame_output = pd.DataFrame({0:{"ProductKey":"Once","Tags":"key1_val1"}, \
                             1:{"ProductKey":"Twice","Tags":"key21_val21; key22_val22"}}).transpose()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 

frame_input = pd.DataFrame({0:{"ProductKey":"Once","SpecificationKey":"key1","SpecificationValue":"val1"}, \
                            1:{"ProductKey":"Twice","SpecificationKey":"key21","SpecificationValue":"val21"}, \
                            2:{"ProductKey":"Twice","SpecificationKey":"key22","SpecificationValue":"val22"}}).transpose()

frame_input['kv'] = frame_input['SpecificationKey'] + '_' + frame_input['SpecificationValue']

frame_input.groupby('ProductKey')['kv'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x.values)).reset_index()
```

Output

```
    ProductKey  Tags
0   Once        key1_val1
1   Twice       key21_val21; key22_val22
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `set_index` and `agg` with a `groupby`

```
frame_input.set_index('ProductKey').agg('_'.join,1).groupby(level=0).agg(';'.join)

ProductKey
Once                   key1_val1
Twice    key21_val21;key22_val22
dtype: object
```